# CSS- Navigation List Items appearing below Nav div. But looks find in Chrome?

Tags: css, navigation, dreamweaver

My navigation looks fine in Chrome but in Firefox and IE, the list items appear below (about 15 pixels below) the nav container div. Can someone please help me?

Here is the link: [http://jwstudio.us/bkpa/](http://www.jwstudio.us/bkpa)

The CSS:

## nav {

```
position: relative;
background-image: none;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
float: left;
background-color: #DBD0CA;
z-index: 3;
margin-top: -115px;
margin-left: -2px;
height: 29px;
width: 945px;
margin-right: 10px;
background-position: left;
```

}

## nav ul {

```
position: relative;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
height: 27px;
z-index: 4;
padding-top: 3px;
margin-top: -115px;
```

}

## nav ul li a {

```
position: relative;
height: 27px;
float: left;
z-index: 5;
text-align: left;
padding-left: 11px;
list-style-type: none;
text-decoration: none;
color: #8F181B;
font-weight: normal;
font-size: 16px;
font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
padding-top: 3px;
padding-right: 10px;
padding-bottom: 0px;
background-color: #DBD0CA;
```

}

## nav ul li a:hover, a:active {

```
position: relative;
height: 27px;
color: #FFF;
background-image: url(images/nav_rollover.png);
z-index: 6;
padding-top: 3px;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You need to reset the padding on the `ul` as it is the left padding that is causing the element to go to the next line:

```
nav ul {

  position: relative;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type: none;
  height: 27px;
  z-index: 4;
  padding-top: 3px;
  margin-top: -115px;
  padding: 0;          // added
}
```

Comment: Ah, life saver! Thank you. Does anyone know of a good guide I can use for adding dropdown submenus to this that won't undo everything I've done?